# Get cells from another sheet based on criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, office365, cells

I'm trying to build a simple helper to control my expenses.

1. One sheet has a list of all financial movements (income and payments), with these details:

| Date | Amount | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02/02/21 | -1000.00 | Rent |
| 02/03/21 | -1200.00 | Rent |
| 12/03/21 | 345.00 | Sale |
| 13/03/21 | 121.60 | Sale |

2. Another sheet has a monthly sum of the values grouped by type:

| Date | Rent | Sale |
| --- | --- | --- |
| feb/21 | -1000.00 | 0.00 |
| mar/21 | -1200.00 | 466.60 |

The types won't change (get added or removed).

Besides the formulas, is there any way to automatically get all rows from the first sheet (below row #1) and display automatically in a new row in the second sheet, without having to manually add another row?

Comment: Use a structured table for your data, then use a pivot table that refers back to the structured table for your output.

Comment: It kind of works, it just does not update (I put some values in April by mistake and changed back to March, but April still appears in the pivot table with the old value) and it adds a `<01/fev/21` entry.

Comment: You can use PivotTable and Group option to get the result directly, if you need I can provide the steps here.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my issue by using a `SumIfs` formula, along with my list of expenses, with types:

**Formula:**
`=SUMIFS(values;types;"Income";dates;">="&$A3;dates;"<="&DATE(YEAR($A3);MONTH($A3)+1;0))`

**Explanation:**
`SUMIFS`: range; (criteria_range; criteria) x **for each criteria**
`values`: Named range for the values, spanning from `B2` to `B∞` on my first sheet.

`types`: Named range for the types of expenses, spanning from `C2` to `C∞` on my first sheet.
`"Income"`: The criteria for the range `types`. Only selects rows with the type being `Income`.

`dates`: Named range for the dates, spanning from `A2` to `A∞` on my first sheet.
`">=" &$A3`: The criteria for the range `dates`. Only selects rows with the date being greater than first column of the second sheet (where the month is located).

`dates`: Named range for the dates again...
`"<=" &DATE(YEAR($A3);MONTH($A3)+1;0))`: The criteria for the range `dates`. Only selects rows with the date being smaller than last day of the month of the date on the first column of the second sheet (where the month is located). Similar to `EOMONTH()`, which for some reason was not accepting my date.

I just needed to copy and paste that formula, change the type criteria and that was it. Also, to add a new month I just copy the row using the select and drag.

Comment: it would be even more effective if you replaced the criteria with a cell reference rather than a hard coded type name (for example replace `"Income"` with `C$1` or wherever you have your column headers)

Comment: Yes, I did that afterwards. I had to change the name for other person and it came to me that idea. :)

Comment: Nice. Thank you for coming back and answering your own question. Caring is sharing.